# Avoiding partial object instantiation

Tags: design-patterns, objectinstantiation

I'm facing a design related dilemma in my project & I'd really appreciate if I could get some suggestions. There's a POJO with around 20-25 fields & in some cases this object is partially instantiated as per the need. In my view this is not a good practice & should be avoided perhaps by using inheritance or composition. I'm looking for suggestions on best way to implement the object creation logic (a design pattern perhaps) so as to avoid partial instantiation. Currently, objects are being created using builder pattern.

Basically, it is a swing application. Data is taken from different fields (20-25) of a JDialog & passed to the next window to be displayed for confirmation. This data is passed on using a POJO. This POJO is currently instantiated using builder pattern. But I am looking for a way to implement this where the POJO isn't partially instantiated & used in other cases where only a few fields needs to be passed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would help if you give us an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a class with parameters that are only used under some conditions and are not needed under the others, you definately should do some refactoring. Try [Extract Class](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractClass.html) refactoring, for example, to group some parameters and methods. If you have some typecodes, that indicate the need in some parameters, think about [replacing typecode with subclasses](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceTypeCodeWithSubclasses.html)
if typecode is not changing during lifetime of an object or replace t[ypecode with state/strategy](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceTypeCodeWithStateStrategy.html) otherwise. Then just move fields and methods from original class to these newly created classes.

I recomend you to read Martin Fowler's Refactoring book. It's just awesome and very helpful.

The builder pattern is ok, but you may want to implement factory method pattern for object creation.

Comment: Thank Andrei. Those were some very helpful links. 

Can you please also give an example of how factory method pattern implementation will help discourage partial object creation when the object has 20-25 members.

Comment: @mindReader, when you use a factory method, you basicaly give to consumer of your class a limited set of options on object creation. For example, if your object has properties that must be field and several sets of properties that are filed only under some conditions, you can implement one factory method for each condition, thus ensuring that an object is created in a valid state. More effective way to use a factory method, however, is to produce some subclasses of parent class(if you do some refactoring beforehand and manage to split your big object to a hierarchy). Hope this helps :)